# why they are not here

Tags: discussion

not a good title I know. But just look at top month user profile score diagram ,More of them are descending. So where are they? I truly afraid about all negative points to this question, But I can take lots of example.

Comment: Could you show us a specific example?

Comment: yes like terdon and radu and bodhi

Comment: and also briam and raj

Comment: But what graphs are you talking about? ***Show*** me what you're talking about. Links, screenshots.

Comment: on the users profile there is chart not graph, I said wrong

Comment: I am afraid if this is time wasted question ,So if there is I will delete that , but if look at their profile you will see their score is descending

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you're talking about this chart... This is mine.

[image]

This isn't a running total of reputation, it's a daily chart. It's how much rep a user earns per day. Some days aren't as good as others frankly because we can't all have 700-rep days every day. There aren't always perfect/popular enough questions or we just have other stuff to do.

And given that it's just turning into summer, a lot of people do have other things to do and would much rather be out on a bike than melting in front of a computer.

I wouldn't worry about it. I don't think it's a trend.